# Custom voice Actions by Google ok

Tags: java, android, google-voice, google-voice-actions

I wanted to implement google voice action,in which when user say "Set an Reminder", this action should done by my app.
This part i already done.

now how can i put different set of question that should ask by google 
and user should given input.

Scenario is:

User says :- Ok google set an alarm

Google shows all app which has the capability of doing this action and then user select is.
Now when user select action via my app then "google ok" should ask custom question which i set in my app.

How can i do that, i have seen set of tutorial but still didn't figure it out.

Comment: have you found the solution ? @Mukesh Gupta